# Unknown statistical formulae

Tags: statistics

Could someone kindly tell me what these formulae represent? Sorry for the lack of information but its all I have.

[image: More info]

[image: Formulae]

[image]

Comment: $g_{ij}$ is a measure of skewness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness, $\bar{x}$ is the average of $x_{ij}$ and $\sigma_g$ seems to be a small sample correction factor, but I am not sure which or for what unless you share more context.

Comment: @Math-fun I have edited my post to include more info

Comment: Thanks for sharing more; I am, however, not sure if I could help any more about $\sigma_g$.

Comment: @Math-fun Thanks for your help, could you see the last screenshot that I added? Perhaps it is more familiar to you?